# Replace last forward slash in string with other character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace the last forward slash in a series of url strings, to exchange that forward slash for a number sign, like so -

```
http://example.com/about/our-company
```

to

```
http://example.com/about#our-company
```

Using JS with jQuery I've tried applying the replace function on each string but not sure as how to target just the last forward slash.

```
$('.submenu a').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    url = url.replace(/\//g, '#');
    console.log(url);
    // replaces all
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = "http://one/two/three/four";
console.log(str.replace(/\/(?=[^\/]*$)/, '#'));
```

That says: "replace the slash that is followed by either nothing or characters that do not include another slash, right to the end."

Comment: Thanks Utkanos! That worked perfectly except I realized all the urls are generated with a trailing slash at the end... doh! Assuming this is always the case, is there a similar way to target the _second_ last forward slash? I should probably do this in another way, I know.

Comment: Not without hugely complicating the pattern. Easiest would be to first strip out the trailing slash (you can always add it back later). So: `var str = "http://one/two/three/four/".replace(/\/$/, '');`

Comment: True, that would probably be the smoothest option. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.submenu a').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var idx = url.lastIndexOf("/");
    url = url.substring(0, idx) + '#' + url.substring(idx+1);
    console.log(url);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try splitting Url based on `/`:

```
url = 'http://example.com/about/our-company';
tokens = url.split('/');
expected_url = tokens.slice(0, tokens.length-1).join('/') + '#' + tokens[tokens.length-1];

console.log(expected_url);
# Prints 'http://example.com/about#our-company'
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
var str="http://example.com/about/our-company";
var tmp=str.split("").reverse().join("");
tmp=tmp.replace("/","#");
str=tmp.split("").reverse().join("");

//output:

str = http://example.com/about#our-company
```